# How do I exclude the rows with '0' values but not the rows with NULL values in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column `reference` under my table. It includes `NULL`, `0` and `1` as its values. I want to exclude the rows that contain `0`. Also, I want the rows with `NULL` values to appear. I tried doing `reference != 0` but it also excludes the rows with `NULL` value. How do I prevent that?

Comment: It's just how `NULL` is: `SELECT NULL!=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NULL` save comparisons.  In MySQL, this is `<=>` for equality.  So, you can do:

```
where not (reference <=> 0)
```

In standard SQL, this would be:

```
where reference is distinct from 0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT reference FROM yourTable WHERE reference = 1 OR reference IS NULL;
```

That will return only values which you want

Answer (score 2):

`NULLS` are a tricky beast- you cannot compare a null to 0, so `null != 0` always returns unknown, which is treated as a `FALSE` in your case. Instead, you can specify nulls in your statement:

```
... WHERE reference IS NULL OR reference != 0
```

or you can replace null with another value in the evaluation:

```
... WHERE COALESCE(reference, 2) != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

NULLs in Databases represents a missing value, this means if you do a comparison with null the result is always unknown.

Databases hence follow a Ternary logic or a Three-valued logic 3VL, so a logical expression in SQL results in True, false and Unknown. So when you ask for `reference != 0` NULLs are not returned as they are evaluated to UNKNOWN instead of TRUE

To answer your problem you need to include both the checks i.e
 `select reference from tablename where reference is null or reference = 1`

Search for Three-Valued Logic in databases or NULL handling in databases for more information

Comment: I tried this as well, but `reference is null` returns those values that includes the rows with value 0 as well..

Comment: This is a tested Query, and `where <col_name> is null` is the standard SQL syntax for matching NULL columns. I do not see why it will not work